# Is it possible to resize a web page for different screens resolutions while maintaining a preset aspect ratio set by a given height and width?

Tags: html, css

I have set the height and width of my parent div to:

```
width:1060px;
height:650px;
```

Which gives me an appearance as far as its size in Chrome on my 720 laptop but when I plug the  1080 TV through the HDMI it's too little on the screen.
I wonder if there is a way to resize the parent div to keep the same distance I get from top/bottom/right/left for 16:9 ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to trigger a resize on the container each time on orientation change with js, then calculate your designed width height aspect ratio, then resize your container to screen.height, then multiply your screen height * your desired aspect, then that result is your width, then check if your width is not minor than screen width, if not is good, if true make the same but in backwards, dividing screen width / desired aspect ratio. lastly center your container in the screen with js or css.

that is the idea, i know works because i ve done it, probably there will be an easy way to accomplish the same.

In this way you can build percentually inside the container and will allways look the same in any kind of stuff, the only change will be a strip on the width or height depending your aspect ratio and your device specs, but it will be allways at biggest possible way.

EDIT,

Is something like;

```
var ratio = 1060/650;

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('#container')
        .css({width: screen.width + 'px', height: screen.width*ratio + 'px'});
    if ($('#container').height() > screen.height) {
        $('#container')
            .css({width: screen.height/ratio + 'px',height: screen.height+'px'});
    }
    $('#container').css({left: (screen.width - $('#container').width()) / 2+'px',
                     top: (screen.height - $('#container').height()) / 2+'px'});

});
```

In jsfiddle wont be nice as this is using screenwidth (you could also use innerHeight, depends if you are going full screen).

Didnt test it but thats the general idea

Comment: Buenas Santiago. Would you happen to have a JSFiddle so I can have a better idea? (please refer to my comment to Josan's answer). Gracias

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a responsive design. In order for your page to resize, you have to start using percentages instead of fixed widths.

For example, change your `width:1060px;` to `width:90%;`. The height can stay the same, but if you wanted it to get taller, you can set `height:100%` and that adjusts according to the content on the page.

Also, instead of using `px` for `text-size`, use `em`. `em` is like percentages for text.

[Here is a great tutorial that helped me a lot with responsive design.](http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/create-fluid-layouts-html5-and-css3-9122768)

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. The thing is that I want to maintain the aspect ratio of the image and also to have it not to change when the window is shrunk (and only then having scroll bars). The trick here is to maintain a relative size when going from 720 to 1080.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media Queries to specify styles for different screen resolutions & sizes. Your browser will choose the respective style depending on the size of the view port.

Read more about that here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries